# Create table in MS Access with all data and columns from Table 1 and add rows from Table 2

Tags: ms-access, join

I'm trying to combine two tables together in MS Access (I'm using the Office 365 version). The tables both look something like this:

```
Headword    Spelling    Frequency
 Word1        Sp1a           x
 Word1        Sp1b           y
 Word2        Sp2a           z
```

So I've got a series of headwords and a few different spellings in each, along with their frequencies. These are in two tables.

I want a combined table with **all** the contents from Table 1, and some of Table 2. From Table 2, I only want the rows where the headword matches a headword in Table 1.

I've been trying to make this work using a join code:

```
SELECT Table1.Headword, Table2.Headword, Table1.Spelling, 
        Table2.Spelling, Table1.Frequency, Table2.Frequency, 
FROM Table2 RIGHT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Headword = Table1.Headword;
```

This has added new columns with the data from Table 2, which isn't what I wanted. (Though the data it added was the right data, at least!)

How do I go about joining the tables together in such a way that I have the three original columns from Table 1, and just add the relevant rows from Table 2 to the end?

Comment: You want a [UNION query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Combine-the-results-of-several-select-queries-by-using-a-union-query-3856f16c-0a22-43f2-8c23-29ec44acbc05).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `UNION`Query:

```
SELECT Headword as HW, Spelling as SP, Frequency as Fr
FROM Table1 
UNION
SELECT  Table2.Headword as HW, Table2.Spelling as SP, Table2.Frequency as Fr
FROM Table2 RIGHT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Headword = Table1.Headword;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for your help!